# Unity on trigger enter can't play animation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a noob at c# in unity. I've been trying to trigger an animation "hit" when a rigid body enters a box collider set to Is Trigger. I have the animation clip, and the console shows me that I have "Entered Trigger". I can't seem to get my animation clip to play once this happens. By the way this is regarding 3D models. Can anyone help?

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class newAttack : MonoBehaviour {

        public GameObject tiger;
        public AnimationClip attack;

        private Animation myAnimation;

      /*  IEnumerator Wait()
        {

            myAnimation = GetComponent<Animation>();
            myAnimation.Play(attack.name);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);

        }
    */
        void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
        {
            Debug.Log("Entered Trigger");
            myAnimation = GetComponent<Animation>();
            myAnimation.Play(attack.name);
           // StartCoroutine(Wait());
        }
// Use this for initialization

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update () {

       }
    }
```

Comment: If you print out the Boolean result of myAnimation.Play, do you get true or false? If the animation cannot be found, for instance, the Play method returns false and does no other alerts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use the Animator and play the name of the animation (present in the animator).

The code would like:

```
myAnimation = GetComponent<Animator>();
myAnimation.Play(attack.name);
```

Ref: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.Play.html

Comment: s0me1ne I did as u said, replacing animation with animator helped. My attack animation is working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Joel Don't forget, if the provided answer is a solution to your problem, please mark it as the solution. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from grayed out to filled in.

Comment: Hristo thanks, sorry I am new to stack overflow. It is done